# How to style WTForm fields using custom css classes?

Tags: html, css, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have created a simple form like:

```
class PostForm(FlaskForm):
    # for posting a new blog
    title = StringField("Title", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Post')
```

And my HTML for the form looks like this:

```
<div class="post-project-fields">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <!-- <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title"> -->
                {{ form.title.label }}
                {{ form.title }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul>
                    <!-- <li><button class="active" type="submit" value="post">Post</button></li> -->
                    {{ form.submit }}
                    <li><a href="/" title="">Cancel</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!--post-project-fields end-->
```

The CSS styling for the class **post-project-fields** looks like:

```
.post-project-fields {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    background-color: #121212;
}
.post-project-fields form {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.post-project-fields form input {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 40px;
}
.post-project-fields form ul li button,
.post-project-fields form ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

As the css class is like this, it is not styling the way I want, which is how it would look if I  used HTML forms only (**Only using the commented out lines from the HTML section.**)

**How do I get the specified styling under the CSS class to be added to the wtforms field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements that are generated by `wtforms` are different from those you were initially rendering. Some of your css selectors target elements that don't exist on the page anymore.

For example you used a `button` for submitting the form before

```
<li><button class="active" type="submit" value="post">Post</button></li>
```

and you have a selector that targets this: `.post-project-fields form ul li button`, but

```
{{ form.submit }}

# renders
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Post">
```

So create a selector that targets the input instead.

You could also make a more generic selector that targets any element that has a `type` attribute of value `"submit"`

```
[type="submit"] {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Inspect the generated elements in the browser and create your styles around that.

Comment: `So create a selector that targets the input instead.`
Yes I understand. After looking at how it was getting rendered, it got clear. Thanks for helping. I will try out the `type`  attribute.